# How to pull the latest RSS item from Facebook's public page feed?

Tags: xml, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss, live-tile

I am trying to pull the latest item from my Facebook's page RSS feed. So far, I am able to find out the public RSS feed URL of a Facebook page's status update:

`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=493782720637150&format=rss20`

Is there a way that I could pull the latest item from the feed by calling it directly from the url; something like this :

`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=493782720637150&format=rss20&itemid=1`

NOTE: Facebook updates the feed depending on the status update, so in that sense I would like to pull (or retrieve or simply **view**) the latest, 2nd latest, 3rd latest item and so on, by simple get via URL.
I am doing this for creating a live tile for my Windows 8.1 Start Screen for my site `http://www.thepirategamer.tk/`.

So I have to configure the `browserconfig.xml` file here : `http://www.thepirategamer.tk/browserconfig.xml`

Thanks in advance! :)